# Google Cloud CronJob NodeJs fails and no logs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a google cloud app ( with nodeJS ) . That have 1 endpoing with the app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

And a cronJob with a cron.yaml that calls to this endpoint like this :

```
 cron:
- description: "Lead Data Update"
  url: /cronjobPrivate/processLeads
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

I'm gettin crazy because if i try to access from the url of my cloud app like

https://[my-project].appspot.com/cronjobPrivate/processLeads The response is correct and the app is working.

But the cronjob always says "fails" and does not create any record on the logs.

I have read the documentation of google but i didn't find nothing. Maybe i'm missing something between the cronjobs <-> app service ...but i don't know what...